# Does the "Temporal" determinateness apply to both temporal and non-temporal entities?

Tags: time, heidegger, being-and-time

Heidegger wrote in Being and Time that:

> In both pre-philosophical and philosophical usage the expression
>   'termporal' has been pre-empted by the signification we have cited; in
>   the following invetigations, however, we shall employ it for another
>   signification. Thus the way in which Being and its modes and
>   characteristics have their meaning determined primordially in terms of
>   time, is what we shall call its 'Temporal' determinateness. ... Thus the fundamental ontological task of Interpreting Being as such includes working out the Temporality of Being.

And that:

> A distinction has been made between "temporal" entities (natural
>   processes and historical happenings) and "non-temporal" entities
>   (spatial and numerical relationships).

Do the two snippets conflict with each other?

Comment: Can you 'think' without time? I'm not clear on your question.. but while 1+1=2 independently of time... Without time there would be no consciousness to ponder that fact.